# Powershell: List Memory and CPU usage of Process

Tags: powershell, cpu, ram

i want to write a Powershell script, that gives me the cpu & memory usage of 2 process.
So i have start with the memory:

```
$ProcessNames = @('Tomcat8.exe','sqlservr.exe')

 
# Get Computer Object
$CompObject =  Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem
$Memory = ((($CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $CompObject.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize)
 
Write-Host "Memory usage in Percentage:" $Memory
        
$processMemoryUsage =  Get-WmiObject WIN32_PROCESS | Where-Object { $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name } | Select-Object processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb)}}
$processMemoryUsage
```

that works. After this CPU...

```
$ProcessName1 = "tomcat8"
$ProcessName2 = 'sqlservr'


$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Sample1 = (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName1)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Sample1 | Select `InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 3)}}

$Sample2 = (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName2*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Sample2 | Select `InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 3)}}
```

That works also...

But when i combine the 2 parts

```
$ProcessNames = @('Tomcat8.exe','sqlservr.exe')

$ProcessName1 = "tomcat8"
$ProcessName2 = 'sqlservr'

$CompObject =  Get-WmiObject -Class WIN32_OperatingSystem
$Memory = ((($CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $CompObject.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $CompObject.TotalVisibleMemorySize)
 
Write-Host "Memory usage in Percentage:" $Memory
        
$processMemoryUsage =  Get-WmiObject WIN32_PROCESS | Where-Object { $ProcessNames -contains $_.Name } | Select-Object processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb)}}
$processMemoryUsage

$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Sample1 = (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName1)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Sample1 | Select `InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 3)}}

$Sample2 = (Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName2*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Sample2 | Select `InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 3)}}
```

I get only the mem Usage and not the cpu usage. But i dont understand why.

```
Memory usage in Percentage: 53,8351717481016

ProcessName                           Mem Usage(MB)                                                                                                                                                           
-------------                         -----------                                                                                                                                                                      
sqlservr.exe                             2948                                                                                                                                                                             
Tomcat8.exe                             10360
```

Can anyone me explain the mistake?

Many thanks

Pascal

Comment: PowerShell is combining the output of both `Select-Object processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.ws / 1mb)}}` and `Select InstanceName,@{Name="CPU %";Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 3)}}` into one output table but only listing the properties of the 1st object which would be processname and Mem Usage(MB).  Add `Out-Host` to the end of each output line to force the output of those objects separately from the others e.g. change line 12 to `$processMemoryUsage | Out-Host`